# How to generate unique ID from spl_object_hash() function in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I have a table of customers where i need to generate unique id for each customer manually rather auto increment it in mysql. How to achieve this? I was suggested the below code with `uniqid(md5(spl_object_hash($custApp)), false);` function:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");

$custApp = json_decode(base64_decode($data));

$custApp->Id = uniqid(md5(spl_object_hash($custApp)), false);
```

But i am not getting how to use this function in my code

Comment: `time()` is best unique value

Answer (score -1):

use `sha1($nombre_costumer)` and save the value how your id unique

Comment: what $nombre_costumer variable is?